# Laravel local vue component registration

Tags: laravel, vue-component

I know I can register global components in the file located in resources/js/app.js.
I know when I do this I can use these component in any place (because they are global).

But I don't want that. I have a big application and different functionalities solved in different routes. So I don't want the whole components available in all my views.

How can I register locally the components I want to be available only in one view?

Thanks

Comment: Is the view just a blade file or is it a vue component itself?

Comment: The view is a blade template yes

Answer (score 2):

Vue js register component in local:

**step-1 )** storing the component object in a variable:

```
var demo = {
data: function() {
    return {
        message: 'This is a local components.'
    };
},
    template: `
        <div>
             <h1>Component: {{ message }}</h1>
         </div>
    `
};
```

**Step-2 )** Add a component property with the components that we want to register locally.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app1',
     components: { /*Here we have added property*/
        'demo': demo
    }
});
```

**Step-3 )** Template

```
<div id="app1">
     <demo></demo>
</div>
```

*Notice: This property should be an `object` and contain `key-value` pairs of tag names and configuration objects.

Comment: I understand this, but in which js file may I put this code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by importing the component in your parent vue component

```js
<template>
    <div>        
        <child-component></child-component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from '@/folder/ChildComponent'

export default {

    components: {
        ChildComponent
    },    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the approach that I follow.

- Create a new file in your components folder in `resources/js/components/YourComponent.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
      <h2>My awesome component</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
        
}
</script>
```

- And in the view where you want the component, you can import it like below

```html
<template>
  <div>
      <h2>Import another component</h2>
      <awesome-component></awesome-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import awesomeComponent from "./components/YourComponent.vue";
export default {
    components: {
        'awesome-component': awesomeComponent
    }    
}
</script>
```

Comment: This throws an error ``{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 18,
  "colno": 1
}``